Implementation of "Manifold reconstruction using tangential Delaunay complexes"
I am looking for an implementation of the paper:
"Manifold reconstruction using tangential Delaunay complexes"
It seems the main author is Arijit Ghosh, however, it seems he doesn't want to be contacted as I cannot find a contact email anywhere on his academic pages. To be respectful of that, I am trying to nonetheless find an implementation of the algorithm delineated in the paper, in any language.

There's nothing disrespectful in contacing researchers regarding their research. If anything most would be happy to oblige if they have the code. It's only a plus for them if this results in a citation. Go to this paper: https://hal.science/hal-02267620v1 the e-mails are inside (though it could be that those are old e-mail addresses). The reason people avoid posting their e-mail explicily on the web is because it gets scrapped and you get tons of spam.
